# Amazon EC2 error " WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" even after changing the permission on Microsoft WSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

I am using microsoft ubuntu terminal to connect to my EC2 instance using PEM keys. According to the suggestions to this question I did change the permission. Even then I am getting the error

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for 'pem_key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "pem_key.pem": bad permissions
ec2-****.us-***.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here is what I have tried...

```
chmod 600 pem_key.pem
ssh -i "pem_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-****.us-***.compute.amazonaws.com
```

How can I solve this issue. Here is my configuration:

OS : Windows 10

Shell : Microsoft Ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 4):

The recommendation permission for private keys is **400**.

```
chmod 400 <yours>.pem
```

Please try as above.

**Also: Windows Terminal(Beta)**

I met this case 1 month ago also. It's because of `Terminal` is stills in `Beta` version. You better use `Ubuntu Subsystem` instead or try to update it into the latest version. I have tried in the latest version and it works.

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: What is the error? Can you post here?

Comment: `Permissions 0555 for 'ATG_party.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "ATG_party.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@ec2-52-39-15-72.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Can you `ls -alh <yours>.pem` to see if it shows like this or not? this supposes to be read as `400`:
`-r--------`

Comment: its showing `-r-xr-xr-x`

Comment: You already did the `chmod 400 <yours>.pem` right? I met this case before, it's because of `Windows Terminal` which is still in `Beta`. Can you try to update this software into the latest version? or use `Ubuntu Subsystem` instead.

Comment: yes, Will try and get back to you